# User-Defined Conversion Operator Ignored for Class Template (Not So for Non-templates)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, implicit-conversion, template-argument-deduction

This code does compile (the important point is that `F()` only accepts `A`s, and since there is an implicit conversion from `B` to `A`, I can easily pass a `B` to it.)

```
struct A {};

struct B {
    constexpr operator A () const {return {};}
};

void F (A a) {}

int main() {
    F(B());
    return 0;
}
```

But the templated version does not compile:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {};

template <typename T>
struct B {
    constexpr operator A<T> () const {return {};}
};

template <typename T>
void F (A<T> a) {}

int main() {
    F(B<int>());
    return 0;
}
```

with the following error on GCC (and equivalent on MSVC):

> error: no matching function for call to ‘F(B<int>)’

(with additional info that there is an `F(A<>)` but `B` does not inherit from `A`.)

For the record, implementing an implicit conversion operator in `A` doesn't help either.

Why doesn't the template version compile? Am I missing something? Or there is actually no way to do it with class templates?!

(Note: I know that I can explicitly cast `B` to `A` at call site; this is not something I prefer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions) doesn't consider implicit conversion.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

The template parameter `T` must be deduced at first (before overload resolution), but given the parameter `A<T>` with argument `B<int>`, `T` can't be deduced from them; then compilation fails.

As the workaround, you can use explicit conversion as you said, or specify the template argument explicitly.

```
F<int>(B<int>());
```

Comment: Damn... Is there nothing in the standardization pipeline; a proposal or something that helps with this?! Anyways, thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 3):

As better explained by songyuanyao, the template parameter `T` must be deduced before.

You can solve the problem explicating the `T` type

```
F<int>(B<int>());
```

but I understand that can be annoying.

So, as workaround for your problem, I propose another template function that deduce `T` before calling `F()`

```
template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
void G (C<T> const & c)
 { F<T>(c); }
```

so you can call `F()`, passing through `G()`, without explicating the `T` type

```
G(B<int>{});
```